# Trying to use the actual 'day of the week' to show api data in react native

Tags: json, rest, react-native

This is my first post here at StackOverflow.

I've tried to search the internet for a while now, but probably because i don't now what to search exactly I can't find the answer online.

I have done a react-native beginners tutorial on how to make an api call and list the results in a flatlist. Everything is working fine, but when I try to add another field that show's the opening hours of that particular day it only works when I hardcode it like this:

```
        <Text style={styles.hours}
        numberOfLines={1}>{item.day5}</Text>
```

This correctly shows the opening hours of Friday, provided by the api. What I would likt though, is to show the opening hours of the actual day of today.

I already managed to calculate the day number and show it in the console by:

```
        let date = new Date();
        let dow = date.getDay();

        console.log( 'The day is ', dow );
```

This returns the correct day number. I'm sure it is probably something really simple but I still can't figure out how to use this day number to actually show the current day's opening hours.

Anyone here who can help me out?

Regards, Jelle